# How to update the state inside a function wrapped in useCallback hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, usecallback

Having the following component:

```
import { useMemo, useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { CellProps } from 'react-table';

import {
  useDataTable,
  DataTable,
  useOnRowClick,
  useRowHighlight,
  IconMenu
} from '../ui-components';

import { useGetTriggers } from '../../hooks';
import { ICalculationEngine } from '../../types';

export function MyComponent() {
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState<null | number>(null);
  const { data } = useGetTriggers();
  const [isEditMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);

  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(data);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedIndex(selectedIndex);
  }, [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex]);

  const onRowClick = (triggerIndex: number) => {
    setEditMode(false);
    setSelectedIndex(triggerIndex);
  };

  const testFun = useCallback(() => {
    setEditMode(!isEditMode);
  }, [isEditMode]);

  console.log('isEditMode! ', isEditMode);

  const tableState = useDataTable({
    columns: useMemo(
      () => [
        {
          Header: 'Name',
          accessor: 'name'
        },

        {
          id: '1',
          Cell: ({ cell }: CellProps<ICalculationEngine['Trigger']>) => {
            if (cell.row.index === selectedIndex) {
              return (
                <IconMenu
                  items={[
                    {
                      title: 'edit',
                      onClick: testFun
                    }
                  ]}
                />
              );
            }
            return <div></div>;
          }
        }
      ],
      [selectedIndex, testFun]
    ),
    data: tableData,
    options: {
      onRowClick: onRowClick
    },
    plugins: [useOnRowClick, useRowHighlight]
  });

  useEffect(() => setTableData(data), [data]);

  return <DataTable dataTableInstance={tableState} />;
}

export default MyComponent;
```

It is building a table with some data in `DataTable` which receives as props the content of the table, the columns: `tableState`. It only has 2 columns, one called Name and a clickable one.

When that one is clicked it must change that state of `isEditMode` from false to true.

There is a function called `testFun` which must to that but it doesn't work, the state isn't updating.

If the state is set to true by other actions, when the user clicks another row however, the state updates to false, in `onRowClick` function.

What is wrong with `testFun` that it doesn't update it? It is because of useCallback wrapping it? If I remove the wrapper, VS Code will say that:

> The 'testFun' function makes the dependencies of useMemo Hook (at line
> 66) change on every render. Move it inside the useMemo callback.
> Alternatively, wrap the definition of 'testFun' in its own
> useCallback() Hook

and still it doesn't work, it doesn't update the state.

Comment: The `testfn` might be propagate. Try add `e.stopPropagation()` to the top of the `testfn` function body. the `e` is the click event which receive as the first arg of the `testfn`

Comment: @Dilshan I have tried but didn't work

Comment: Are u sure the onClick event triggered on `<IconMenu />` ?

Comment: If you can add a sandbox it will help to find the actual issue. Can't see any other issue other than, what happen if the user did not click on row before click on the `name` column ? And also you do have an infinite triggering useEffect.